# Seaborn Pairgrid: How to share all axes for all off-diagonal plots (i.e each plot shares axes with its mirror)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am trying to plot a 3x3 `sns.PairGrid` of plots. Currently, the axes are shared for the bottom triangle, and the upper triangle separately. Put another way, the x axes and y axes are only shared with their respective columns/row. So the x-axis of plot `(1,0)` is shared with `(0,0)` and `(2,0)`.

However, I would like all the off-diagonal plots to share their axes. So for example, I want `(1,0)` share its x-axis with `(0,0)` and `(2,0)` like before, but *also with* `(0,1)`.

Also, I would prefer it if the y-axes aren't shared with the plots on the diagonal, as those are 1-D kernel density plots, and so if I share their y-axes, some of them will be invisible as the size of the probability density functions isn't the same.

Here's my current code if it helps:

The 3 parameters I am plotting against each other are called 'A', 'C', and 'logsw', and are contained in the `pandas.DataFrame` called `hyperparams`

```
g = sns.PairGrid(hyperparams, diag_sharey=False)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, marker='+')
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
```

And here's a trivial example of the output plot:

[image: The images on the bottom left are scaled differently to the images on the upper right, which is what I'm trying to avoid.]

The images on the bottom left are scaled differently to the images on the upper right, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: One thing you could do is to draw a scatterplot with alpha=0 on the lower triangle. That should get the automatic axes limits set the same (provided that the countour limits are always tighter than the scatter limits, which I think will be the base.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what does alpha=0 do?

Comment: "alpha" is a "synonym" for opacity. This will essentially draw an invisible scatterplot.

Comment: @mwaskom Hi, sorry for revisiting this after such a long time, but I tried what you suggested by adding a `g.map_lower(plt.scatter, alpha=0)` and unfortunately it doesn't seem to match the axes limits.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer on this?  high level, you could manually set the x and y limits and tickmarks.  You could also set variables to what you want to share and then just reuse the variable in the 3 like subplots.  That way, if you need to make an adjustment, you just update the variable and the 3 plots that share it now update all at once.  I just created code for a Pair grid where I set the limits and ticks on all subplots along the y-axis, and all plots along the x-axis.  If you think this sample might help you, check in on these comments and let me know and I will post it

Comment: I ended up manually setting the limits too in the end :) Thanks.

Comment: @TMWP Could u pls post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High level, you could manually set the x and y limits and tickmarks. You could also set variables to what you want to share and then just reuse the variable in the 3 like subplots.

That way, if you need to make an adjustment, you just update the variable and the 3 plots that share it now update all at once.

In the past, I created code for a Pair grid where I set the limits and ticks on all subplots along the y-axis, and all plots along the x-axis in this manner.

Comment: You could delete your comment below the question, it's obsolete now and may distract from your proper answer

Comment: You could use the `set` method in PairGrid which sets a property to all subplot. For example, `g.set(xlim=[-1,1], ylim=[-1,1])`.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way of automatically doing this in Seaborn. The workaround suggested in the comment that seems to have solve the problem is to set the axes limits manually for the diagonal subplots. Using variables for the x and y limits ensures that they only need to be changed in one place when updating the axes ranges.